# Convert single-line .CGI to Multiline in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cgi, invoke-webrequest

I have a media application that outputs the playlist into a handy .CGI web file. When viewing from browser (view-source:http://) is shows it as a list (line 1, 2, 3 etc); however Powershell's Invoke-WebRequest pulls it as one string that's X chars long.

Is there away of having powershell pull the data much the same as the browser views it.

My goal is to be able to select specific lines, say track 4 & 5, -Skip 3, -First 1, etc
I was steering away from exporting it out to text and then importing back...

Thanks

Comment: `(Invoke-WebRequest ...).Content -split '\r?\n'`

Comment: Thank you Mathias, exactly what I needed!. I then added | Select-Object -Skip 2 -First 1 and got my result, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Content` property on the response object you get from `Invoke-WebRequest` contains a single multi-line string - simply split on newlines to get each line as individual strings:

```
$webResponse = Invoke-WebRequest ...

$responseBodyLines = $webResponse.Content -split '\r?\n'
```